# Convert For each arrow function to normal function in GTM

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, arrow-functions

iam writing a script for Google Tag Manager. At the moment i get the following error message: "error in line 4,  character 20: This language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT_2015 mode or better: arrow function." My current code looks like this:

```
function() {
  var products = {{DLV-products}};
  var  total = 0;
  products.forEach(element => {
  total += parseFloat(element.quantity) * parseFloat(element.price);
  });
    return total;
  }
```

Can someone help, how i can convert the for each arrow function to a normal function in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Arrow functions follow this syntax:

```js
(arguments) => {
// code ...
}
```

'Normal' functions follow this syntax:

```js
function (arguments) {
// code ...
}
```

In your case, I suggest:

```js
function() {
  var products = {{DLV-products}};
  var total = 0;

  products.forEach(function (element) {
    total += parseFloat(element.quantity) * parseFloat(element.price);
  });

  return total;
}
```